# quantum and thermal fluctuations in 1D, 2D, 3D

Tags: condensed-matter, solid-state-physics

Why do thermal and quantum fluctuations destroy long-range order in 1D and 2D? Why not in 3D? If the answer is quite elaborated (with many formulas) perhaps a reference would be better. Sorry if this question is too vague, but I personally have no idea how to start with it.

Comment: How large a foam hand do you want? In 1D fluctuations never die out, in 2d they die out slowly. In 3d nature is interesting and in 4d, I believe, it turns incredibly boring incredibly fast, because forces have a much shorter reach, i.e. order/disorder doesn't communicate well over long distances.

Comment: but how do I see all that, with formulas if possible, or physical arguments

Comment: If you are looking for the math, that's in books like "Quantum physics in one dimension" by Thierry Giamarchi, which discusses the thermodynamics of these systems in detail.

Comment: I'm afraid I have no access to it. Any alternative answer? Perhaps a physical description instead of the math?

Answer (score 2):

The higher the dimension, the more phase space you have for your fluctuations to spread. Imagine you make a small local disturbance in your system (caused by e.g. thermal fluctuations). In 1D this disturbance can freely propagate in the system without decaying : it destroys long-range order.

In 3D, the disturbance also propagates but it quickly dies out because its energy gets spread in all directions. Thus the effect of the disturbance is short range and cannot kill long range order.

The 2D case is very special, long range order at finite-T is in most cases destroyed by thermal fluctuations (at least in the case of continuous symmetry breaking) : this is the content of [Mermin-Wagner](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mermin%E2%80%93Wagner_theorem)'s theorem. On the other hand, some very special phase transitions such as the [BKT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kosterlitz%E2%80%93Thouless_transition) transition can occur.

Comment: Note that Mermin-Wagner only applies to continuous symmetries.

Comment: I guess the physical picture makes sense. How could I model the system so as to appreciate such effects?

Comment: @fqq Thanks for the valid point, just edited my post.